# My own backend sends two Objects instead of one in http response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, http, backend

I got a backend in Django which is supposed to send me data, but instead of one object I get two objects (inside of the http response). The weird thing about that, is that it does not happen all the time, sometimes its just one and sometimes there are two... This is how the response looks like (In the network analytics):

```
    {
    "id": 1,
    "sumScore": 270,
    "sumRequests": 55,
    "buttonOne": 55,
    "buttonTwo": 10,
    "buttonThree": 10,
    "buttonFour": 10,
    "buttonFive": 55,
    "buttonSix": 55,
    "buttonSeven": 55,
    "buttonEight": 10,
    "buttonNine": 10,
    "myResult": 4
}{
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_UNIQUE_ID': 'YxTgq5gPaMxcbxlxyS6l0QAAAAM',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/kunden/homepages/29/d920390454/htdocs/MyWebsite',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_UI_SUEXEC_DEFAULT_CHROOT_ID': '14',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_UI_SUEXEC_FSTATD_UNIXSOCKET': '/run/ui-fstatd.suexec.socket',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_UI_SUEXEC_STATISTICS_UNIXSOCKET': '/homepages/sclientMF/http.sock.bin',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_HTTPS': 'on',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY__RSCLVL_CPU': '40',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY__RSCLVL_MEM': '768',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY__RSCLVL_PROCSOFT': '15',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY__RSCLVL_PROCHARD': '27',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY__RSCLVL_JIMDO': '800',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY__RSCLVL_CPU_JIMDO': '60',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY__RSCLVL_MEM_JIMDO': '768',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY__RSCLVL_PROCSOFT_JIMDO': '24',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY__RSCLVL_PROCHARD_JIMDO': '24',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY_HOST': 'api.tor-netzwerk-seminarfach2024.com',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY_VALUE': '/kunden/homepages/29/d920390454/htdocs/MyWebsite:d0000#CPU 6 #MEM 10240 #CGI 524360 #NPROC 12 #TAID 109180236 #LANG 0 #RSCLVL 300 #CHROOT 15',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY_DOCROOT': '/kunden/homepages/29/d920390454/htdocs/MyWebsite',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY_HASH': 'd0000',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY__CPU': '6',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY__MEM': '10240',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY__CGI': '524360',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY__NPROC': '12',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY__TAID': '109180236',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY__LANG': '0',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY__RSCLVL': '300',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY__CHROOT': '15',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_DBENTRY': '/kunden/homepages/29/d920390454/htdocs/MyWebsite:d0000#CPU 6 #MEM 10240 #CGI 524360 #NPROC 12 #TAID 109180236 #LANG 0 #RSCLVL 300 #CHROOT 15',
    'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_STATUS': '200',
    'REDIRECT_UNIQUE_ID': 'YxTgq5gPaMxcbxlxyS6l0QAAAAM',
    'REDIRECT_DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/kunden/homepages/29/d920390454/htdocs/MyWebsite',
    'REDIRECT_HTTPS': 'on',
    'REDIRECT_STATUS': '200',
    'UNIQUE_ID': 'YxTgq5gPaMxcbxlxyS6l0QAAAAM',
    'HTTPS': 'on',
    'HTTP_HOST': 'api.tor-netzwerk-seminarfach2024.com',
    'CONTENT_LENGTH': '48',
    'HTTP_SEC_CH_UA': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="104", "Opera";v="90"',
    'HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_MOBILE': '?0',
    'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36 OPR/90.0.4480.80',
    'HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_PLATFORM': '"Windows"',
    'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/json',
    'HTTP_ACCEPT': '*/*',
    'HTTP_ORIGIN': 'https://tor-netzwerk-seminarfach2024.com',
    'HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE': 'same-site',
    'HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE': 'cors',
    'HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST': 'empty',
    'HTTP_REFERER': 'https://tor-netzwerk-seminarfach2024.com/',
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'PATH': '/kunden/homepages/29/d920390454/htdocs/python_files/venv/bin:/bin:/usr/bin',
    'SERVER_SIGNATURE': '',
    'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Apache',
    'SERVER_NAME': 'api.tor-netzwerk-seminarfach2024.com',
    'SERVER_ADDR': '82.165.89.2',
    'SERVER_PORT': '443',
    'REMOTE_ADDR': '2a02:2454:9595:5a00:516b:2606:c0a6:98d1',
    'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/kunden/homepages/29/d920390454/htdocs/MyWebsite',
    'REQUEST_SCHEME': 'https',
    'CONTEXT_PREFIX': '/system-bin/',
    'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/kunden/usr/lib/cgi-bin/',
    'SERVER_ADMIN': 'webmaster@api.tor-netzwerk-seminarfach2024.com',
    'SCRIPT_FILENAME': '/kunden/homepages/29/d920390454/htdocs/MyWebsite/cgi-bin/application.fcgi',
    'REMOTE_PORT': '32898',
    'REDIRECT_URL': '/cgi-bin/application.fcgi/apache-test/',
    'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',
    'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
    'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST',
    'QUERY_STRING': '',
    'REQUEST_URI': '/apache-test/',
    'SCRIPT_NAME': '/cgi-bin/application.fcgi',
    'PATH_INFO': '/apache-test/',
    'PATH_TRANSLATED': '/kunden/homepages/29/d920390454/htdocs/MyWebsite/cgi-bin/application.fcgi',
    'STATUS': '200',
    'VIRTUAL_ENV': '/kunden/homepages/29/d920390454/htdocs/python_files/venv/bin',
    'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': 'MyWebsite.settings',
    'TZ': 'UTC',
    'wsgi.version': (1,
    0),
    'wsgi.input': <_io.BufferedReader name='<stdin>'>,
    'wsgi.errors': <_io.BufferedWriter name='<stderr>'>,
    'wsgi.multithread': False,
    'wsgi.multiprocess': True,
    'wsgi.run_once': True,
    'wsgi.url_scheme': 'https'
}
```

The first object is supposed to be there, the second isn't. Here is my backend view:

```
    @api_view(["POST"])
def home(request):
    body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    body = json.loads(body_unicode)
    result = body["Result"]
    isItRight = body["wichOnesRight"]

    ip_adress = get_client_ip(request)
    queryset = Lead.objects.all()

    if Lead.objects.all().exists():
            currentValues = updateDigits()
            
            queryset.update(
                sumScore = result + currentValues[9],
                sumRequests = 1 + currentValues[10],
                buttonOne = currentValues[0] + isItRight[0],
                buttonTwo = currentValues[1] + isItRight[1],
                buttonThree = currentValues[2] + isItRight[2],
                buttonFour = currentValues[3] + isItRight[3],
                buttonFive = currentValues[4] + isItRight[4],
                buttonSix = currentValues[5] + isItRight[5],
                buttonSeven = currentValues[6] + isItRight[6],
                buttonEight = currentValues[7] + isItRight[7],
                buttonNine = currentValues[8] + isItRight[8],
                )
            currentValues = updateDigits()
    else:
            obj = Lead()
            obj.save()
    serializer = TestingSerializer(queryset[0], many =False)
    
    return Response({**serializer.data, "myResult": result})
```

and here the frontend:

```
function sendAndGetQuizAverage(points){
    const myPostRequest = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({"Result":points, "wichOnesRight": wichOnesRight}),
        };
    let data
    fetch('xxxx', myPostRequest).then(
        (response) => data = response.json()).then((data) => {showResultAnalyse(data)})
}
```

which throws the error message:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character
> after JSON at position 197

So the content is clearly more than 197 Characters, but in the response header is the following detail:

```
content-length: 197
```

Which is weird because the length I expect is actually 197 Characters, because that is the length of the first object...

If you want to test it, here is my website:
[https://tor-netzwerk-seminarfach2024.com][1]
You have to go to the quiz(upper left corner) and than select in every row one block to be able to submit it.
So, why do I sometimes get the second object and how can I handle it? I am hosting the server on Ionos

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question, just a suggestion:
Remove the link in your example.. It's a security issue, because one could do... dangerous things with it.

[image]

Comment: But you should also not post the URL again.